# Directive applied after filter (or bound to filtered result so Directive is called again)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gagere/en1pg6od/) with html:

```
<div get-width class="output">{{ inputText | uppercase }}</div>
```

And directive:

```
myApp.directive('getWidth', [function () {
  function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.textSize = getTextWidth(element.text(), "95px Arial");
  }

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: link
  };
}]);
```

Trying to have a directive calculate the width of text after all other child directives have been applied and filters have been applied.  Unfortunately it always seems that the filters apply after directives.  The width calculation is always run on "{{inputValue | uppercase}}" instead of on the evaluated values.

I'd be fine if the filter applied afterwards, but then caused the directive to be re-evaluated because the element changed.  But I don't seem to be able to get the directive to bind to the element.

I'd prefer not to pass everything using arguments or pass the $filter service in and manually filter the input before calculating the width as I don't know what filters may be used.  This directive may be used by other developers (it's just an example for now) and so it could contain any input and any number of chained filters.  Is there a way evaluating the element before running getTextWidth()?

This function may be used to adjust elements in the page so I would like to avoid $timeout and causing extra paints (flicker).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: actually, I don't think this is doing what you expect at all.  This directive isn't monitoring the input box for changes, it is performing a one time evaluation on the contents of the div, which is, at the time of that evaluation, the static string `{{ inputText | uppercase }}`, which will **always** evaluate to the same `width=1091.572265625`

Comment: in other words, `element` won't work here, since it cannot parse angular expressions.

Comment: True, I've had it linked to an attribute (input =) that had the value set to inputText which did update the directive when the inputText was updated, but that's also not what I'm trying to do.  Would binding the directive to the element cause it to be evaluated after the element was filtered?  And how would I do that?

Comment: well, you *can* get the `getTextWidth` function to read the `<div>` **after** the angular bindings are done by wrapping the call to it in `$timeout`, but that's only part of the problem; you would also need some sort of watch that would trigger that function to be called each time the text changes, which is not what it is doing now.

Comment: Ah yes, I've had that work with $timeout, unfortunately that is after the paint and causes flicked if the getTextWidth output is used to resize things (which it is, but I reduced things for the example).  I'd like to stay in the same $digest call, or at least before the paint.  I suppose there is no $watch available for an element as its not part of the model/scope?

Comment: `$timeout(functionCall,0)` will cause a `0` second delay, which should mean you don't see any flicker effect.  unfortunately, though, any time you use `element` or `document`, you are dropping into JQLite (or JQuery, if avalible) territory, where angular as almost 0 control.

Comment: this feels to me like a place where you follow the angular guideline of using `$interval`, but that may be overkill for what you are trying to achieve.  Something similar to https://jsfiddle.net/en1pg6od/8/.  Please note that I had to replace the angular script with something newer than 1.0.1 for that example to work....

Comment: also please note, this really has nothing to do with the filter, the same thing would be an issue even if you were using `{{inputText}}`.  It has to do with when the expression is evaluated.

Comment: an alternative to using `$interval` would involve putting a watch on `inputText`, and calling your function whenever that value changed.  However, that would require you to pass `inputText` as a parameter.  You could also use `$broadcast` or `$emit` and run the function then.  Essentially, you are only calling the function during the constructor of the directive (hence it being only called once, not during a `$digest`), when what you really want is it to be called when the data changes.

Comment: Not sure why I had that version selected.  The profiler still shows multiple paints with your $interval solution.

Comment: yes, the interval solution would, because it's recalling the `getTextWidth` every second.  I was just using that as an example of one of the many ways to get your function to fire sometime other than the directive controller constructor, which is essentially at the beginning of the app lifecycle.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a dummy filter that would be tacked onto the end of the filter chain that calls $emit?